# Как правильно создавать модели данных

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение "Список дел/задач".

Есть модель, которая содержит заголовок и приоритет задачи, а данные берет из бд. В зависимости от приоритета задачи, я меняю дизайн на текущей активити. К примеру, если приоритет задачи высокий, то делаю красный фон.

Модель:

```
public class Task {
    private String mTitle;
    private int mPriority;

    public Task(String title, int priority) {
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mPriority = priority;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return mPriority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int mPriority) {
        this.mPriority = mPriority;
    }
}
```

В поле mPriority я храню число, от 0 до 2.

0 - низкий приоритет, 1 - средний, 2 - высокий

И далее уже в активити через switch делаю что мне надо

```
switch(task.getPriority) {
    // Низкий приоритет задачи
    case 0:
        // Сделать фон допустим зеленым.
        // еще какие то действия с дизайном.
    break;
    // Средний приоритет задачи
    case 1:
        // Тут код
    break;
    // Высокий приоритет задачи
    case 2:
        // Тут код
    break;
}
```

Понятное дело что хранить число приоритета и далее делать проверки в switch не правильно. Ведь вдруг я захочу добавить еще один приоритет: "3 - Супер высокий приоритет", тогда мне в каждом месте где используется приоритет задачи придется редактировать код.

Только учусь программированию, по этому объясните на "пальца", как решаются такие проблемы :)

Пока я думаю что нужно создать еще одну модель TaskPriority, а в ней поля title, color;

А в самой модели Task, за место поля int mPriority, сделать TaskPriority mPriority;

Но не уверен что это решают таким путем.

Comment: вместо абстрактного числа приоритета, вы можете хранить реальное число - цвет фона для своей задачи и вводить любое кол-во приоритетов без изменения логики. При создании заметки выбираете из любого набора фиксированных данных, хоть сразу цвета, как в гугл календаре, хоть условное слово (как низкий, средний, высокий) - в базу пишите закреплённый цвет. при выводе заметки, фон красите цветом из этого поля. при фиксированном наборе цветов это все так же будут  числа (код RGB) по которому выборку организовать так же просто, как и по абстрактным 1, 2, 3, если требуется фильтрация по этому полю.

Answer (score 1):

Основное - нужно разделять данные от представления. Их нельзя друг с другом смешивать.

1) У вас есть `Model` - они же данные (то как вы отображаете данные из БД в модель - это отдельная большая песня)

2) Далее у вас `View` - то как вы собираетесь отображать/представлять/показывать

3) Как теперь сделать общение между моделью и представлением? (`model vs. view`)

В п. 3 начинается разброд и шатание. Все упирается в концепт, если угодно в философию, если быть точнее называется *архитектурный паттерн*.

Отголоски этого разброда и шатания можно почитать погуглив ключевые слова:

- MVC - model, view, controller
- MVP - model, view, presenter
- MVVM - model, view, viewmodel
- MVI - model, view, intent

Для Android сейчас кошерным является концепция [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), впрочем лет 5 назад все верещали от MVP, а лет 10 назад с экранов не сходил MVC, но ничего. Еще через пару лет - придумают что нибудь другое.

В общем реализуйте MVVM, тем более что Android заточен под него.

[Практическое руководство здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/dataart/blog/272737/)